# passing a variable to partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In a view I have a foreach loop and within the loop, I would like to pass looped variable to a partial view which will be used in a modal:

```
@foreach (var ladder in Model.CurrentLadders)
 {...render some stuff
    @Html.Partial("_SignupSheetPartial",ladder)
```

then in _signupSheetpartial.cshtml

```
    <!-- Modal content-->
    //render stuff using the ladder variable
     <p>ladder.Name</p>
```

However the partial view does not recognise the ladder variable.  Also if I want to use another variable in the partial is there a way to send across more than 1 variable?

Comment: Is your partial view expecting to receive a list ?

Comment: You can pass a model to a partial view.  This could be your variable.  The partial view needs a model declare statement.  In your case the type of CurrentLadders

Answer (score 2):

You partial view needs to know that it will be given a specific model. So make sure it has this line in the beginning:

```
@model Full.Name.Of.Ladder.Class
```

And inside the partial view there is no loop, so there is no loop variable. Instead it should be referenced by `Model`:

```
<p>Model.Name</p>
```

Comment: ok thanks, I guess I will need to do some redesigning since I can't use the loop variable in the partial.

Comment: @user3611219, well from what I can see now the thing that I have suggested is all that is required to enable your code. Generally I do not see any design flaws in what you have, your scenario is pretty common and not alarming at all

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are referring the ladder class in your model so the partial view model knows what to expect

```
@model  namespace of ladder class
```

It is best way to pass your multiple parameters in a class(object) to your partial view. So you need to design your classes in such a way that whatever is needed for partial view are grouped in one class

Hope this helps!